# How about a SE specifically for ID questions?

Tags: discussion

I'm new here.

In my short time here I've seen several movie-ID requests closed as off-topic. Looking at the archives I see that you made a decision about 3 years ago. I don't really understand why why were a problem. I've seen the discussion, and I don't buy it. I think it's rude and unhelpful to just close them.

It's your choice, I suppose. I won't try to persuade you to reverse your decision. However, I do think that ID questions do have a place on SE. They are perfectly acceptible on Literature or Science Fiction & Fantasy, for instance.

Here's a suggestion. How about starting a separate SE forum specifically for movie/TV ID questions.

Comment: SF&E is a far more limited scope than here, and they have very strict rules (e.g. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info ). What works there doesn't necessarily work here. We've tried imposing strict rules and we still got rubbish questions with next to no details (often even without the proper tag!) and the people who posted them got upset when we asked for clarifications. IMHO killing off ID questions has been a great improvement for this site.

Answer (score 8):

This has been suggested on [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) at least three times in the time that I have been visiting StackExchange.

Such a site has never got close to being openend.

The trouble is that a broad *Identify This* site would be too open-ended to manage, and almost all questions would only be of interest to a very small number of people.

But of course, there's nothing to stop you [trying again](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create?category=recreation).